# Meaning of a condition $\left(\Re\left(m^2\right)\geq 0\lor m^2\notin \mathbb{R}\right)$

Tags: conditional

I'm new to using Mathematica. I asked Mathematica to perform the following integration,

```
Integrate[Integrate[q^2*(q/(q^2 + m^2))*Exp[I*q*r*u], {u, -1, 1}], {q, 0, ∞}]
```

Mathematica returned the following answer,

```
ConditionalExpression[(
 Sqrt[π]
   MeijerG[{{-(1/2)}, {}}, {{-(1/2), 1/2}, {0}}, (m^2 r^2)/4])/(
 Sqrt[1/m^2] Sqrt[r^2]), 
 Im[r] < 0 && (Re[m^2] >= 0 || m^2 ∉ Reals)]
```

Now I don't read Mathematica's language! Can anyone tell me what conditions has Mathimatica assumed for the variable $m$?

Comment: Read `||` as a logical "or" and `&&` as logical "and". `Re` means real part.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you actually asking about. In the title you translated correctly the MMA output into a mathematical formulation. So do you have a question about coding in MMA, or are you asking about numbers fulfilling the condition from the title (or, put differently, examples that do not obey it)?